# получить результат выражения в boolean java

Tags: java

Выражение 1+1 >= 4, нужно без if else получить булевский результат, как?

Comment: Для получения булевского результата выражения предложения jf-else никакой роли не играют.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
boolean result = (1+1) >= 4;
```

P.S. Скобки в данном случае добавлены исключительно для удобочитаемости, т.к. приоритет операции сложения выше, чем операции сравнения.

Answer (score 0):

в чем проблема?

```
System.out.println(1 + 1 >= 4);
```

Answer (score -1):

пишешь:

> boolean b = 1+1 >= 4;

и получаешь false

А если написать:

```
boolean b; b = 1+1 == 2;
```

получишь true;